# How to whiten background and blaken grid in a same image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have an image like this. I wan to use HoughLine detection but the image is too dark to recognize the line. Is there a way that can whiten the background and blacken the grid? Is there any algorithms in openCV or python that I can apply? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Do you have codes? Have you tried anything yet? If so what have you tried? Please specify your question a bit more.

Comment: You've already got some answers but just to be clear so you know, Hough looks for *white* lines so you actually want a black background and white lines in the end.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. Is there any to turn this image to perfect black background and white lines? Or any algorithms to detect black line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I try to dilate the image first, then medianBlur it, so I get the background. Use the original gray image to sub the background, I get the frontground ( that is  the grids). Then do some other steps, I get the result like this.

[image]

The code is as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2017.10.04 19:37:43 CST

filename = "data/paper.png"
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

## do morph-dilate-op
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5,5))
dilated = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)
diff1 = 255 - cv2.subtract(dilated, gray)

## do medianBlur
median = cv2.medianBlur(dilated, 15)
diff2 = 255 - cv2.subtract(median, gray)

## do normalize 
normed = cv2.normalize(diff2,None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX )

## save the result 
dst = np.hstack((gray, normed))
cv2.imwrite("result_paper1.png", dst)
res = np.hstack((gray,dilated, diff1,  median, diff2, normed))
cv2.imwrite("result_paper2.png", res)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should try a form of localized adaptive thresholding.
In OpenCV this is called `cv2.adaptiveThreshold`.

See here: http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html for a python example.

The code (from the source above):

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('sudoku.png',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
th2 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
titles = ['Original Image', 'Global Thresholding (v = 127)',
            'Adaptive Mean Thresholding', 'Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding']
images = [img, th1, th2, th3]
for i in range(4):
    plt.subplot(2,2,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

[image: adaptive thresholding]

Comment: Opencv supports adaptive thresholding: http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

Comment: OpenCv hough lines often performs worse on thresholded images (many false positives). Thats why i suggested contrast increase method

Comment: Globally increasing contrast should not change the location of maxima in the Hough Transform. I'm not sure how it works internally in OpenCV, but I'm sure you will get better results if you apply localized thresholding first.

Answer (score 0):

Your image has poor contrast and inconsistent light. You have to make some preprocessing (c++ code here):

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("E:\\Workspace\\KS\\excercise\\oBwBH.jpg", 0);
cv::Mat workingMat;
cv::GaussianBlur(img, workingMat, cv::Size(101, 101), 31, 31); //high blur to extract background light
img = img - 0.7*work; //adjust light level
cv::normalize(img, img, 0, 255, cv::NORM_MINMAX); \\use whole range
cv::medianBlur(img, img, 5); \\remove noise
cv::Canny(img, work, 100, 200); \\extract lines; you could do hough lines instead since it has canny inside.
```

Results (from left to right, canny has all lines, in preview there is some compression issue):
[image]