# Identify a line on an image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

[This is the frame I want to process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upsb8.jpg). I wanted to identify a line in an image. Although, I did that via Canny Edge detection, I tried using the corners too (expecting the dots to cover most of the lines). Counter-intuitively, more dots appeared on the noise in the image than the actual line. I was wondering if anyone knows of a function in OpenCV (Python) to connect these dots intelligently, only to connect over the line, and not the noise.

Help will be much appreciated. 
[I wanted to identify this black line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBXdo.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('fw1.jpeg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
minLineLength = 100
maxLineGap = 10
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[0]:
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imwrite('houghlines5.jpg',img)
```

Comment: Can you please post an example picture?

Comment: Thanks for the pic. Can you post your code? I have no idea where those dots are coming from. Corner detection tries to find 90 degree corners, not edges. If you're trying to detect the black line why not try color detection? [See here for e.g.](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html)

Comment: Forgive my knowledge, but I am pretty new to OpenCV. Can you attach the link of color detection you are talking about?

Comment: I am trying to trace this line and also find a equation of this line. Can you please help me out with a link/resource/code?

Comment: The "see here for e.g." from my last post was a link :). Equations of the line aren't too hard to get, but first, you need to detect the line and get a nice mask. Try out code like in that link to detect dark colors and make a nice mask of the image; update your post with that and it should give a nice place to start from.

Comment: Also it would be preferable if you could link an actual frame from the video without your processing.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Alexander Reynolds,

I was able to detect the line using canny edge detection (and binary thresholding too). Now, I need to get the Cartesian equation of the line. I was reading up on Hough Line, but the code doesn't seem to work. Moreover, I am incognizant of other ways to get the equation of the form y=mx+c.

Comment: import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('fw1')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
minLineLength = 100
maxLineGap = 10
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[0]:
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imwrite('fw1',img)

This is the code I learnt from the website, but it doesn't execute and terminal window doesn't respond to it? It doesn't even points out any errors in it. I can't fathom what is the issue.

Comment: Edit your post to include the code and resulting images; don't post it as a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I have just included the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should increase contrast and get rid of noise in the first place. Contrast increase is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46522515/8682088

Code from source above:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("E:\\Workspace\\KS\\excercise\\oBwBH.jpg", 0);
cv::Mat workingMat;
cv::GaussianBlur(img, workingMat, cv::Size(101, 101), 31, 31); //high blur to extract background light
img = img - 0.7*work; //adjust light level
cv::normalize(img, img, 0, 255, cv::NORM_MINMAX); \\use whole range
cv::medianBlur(img, img, 5); \\remove noise
cv::Canny(img, work, 100, 200); \\extract lines; you could do hough lines instead since it has canny inside.
```

After that I suggest using HoughLines or HoughLinesP in opencv library.